# What are these small tubes soldered into through holes for jumper wires called?

Tags: identification, jumper

I am working with ancient 70s PCBs and have encountered these small metal tube-like posts that appear to be soldered into through-holes.

They are used to make and remove optional jumper connections without further solder.

They seem handy. I'd like to get some for my own projects. What are they called?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called pin receptacles.

Digi-Key carries them in the appropriately named [category](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminals/pc-pin-receptacles-socket-connectors/324).